# Show session name in byobu

Tags: byobu, tmux

Is there any option to have the status bar in byobu display the current tmux session name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default you get the session name (see marked area on the left side) as soon as you add another session  (you might have to wait for some time or refresh the status line with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image: screenshot]

Also:

- <kbd>F8</kbd>: Rename the current window.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>: Rename the current session.

Comment: Ah, you're right. After I removed and reinstalled I began seeing that. I guess I had an older version.